# Iterate over one dataframe to calculate new features - Python

Tags: python, pandas, variables, analytics, feature-engineering

I am using a dataframe of credit card transactions with the following columns:

`timestamp, transaction_id, buyer_id, status`

I want no generate a new column `q_app_1d` that calculates for each `transaction_id`, the amount of previous `transaction_id`'s based on a condition (same `buyer_id`, `status = 1`, difference between `timestamp`'s <= 1 day).

I have tried doing this using self-join (aka joining the dataframe with itself), but have failed to do so successfully.
I know how to do this easily in SQL, but I can't get it working with Pandas.

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Sample input:

```
timestamp, transaction_id, buyer_id, status
01/01/2020 00:00:00, 1, abc123, 1
01/01/2020 00:25:00, 2, abc123, 1
01/01/2020 00:30:00, 3, abc123, 1
01/01/2020 00:45:00, 4, def456, 1
02/01/2020 08:55:00, 5, abc123, 1
02/01/2020 10:55:00, 6, def456, 1
03/01/2020 12:55:00, 7, def456, 1
```

Sample output:

```
timestamp, transaction_id, buyer_id, status, q_app_1d
01/01/2020 00:00:00, 1, abc123, 1, 0
01/01/2020 00:25:00, 2, abc123, 1, 1 #(considers transaction_id 1)
01/01/2020 00:30:00, 3, abc123, 1, 2 #(considers transaction_id 1,2)
01/01/2020 00:45:00, 4, def456, 1, 0
02/01/2020 08:55:00, 5, abc123, 1, 0 #(more than one day since transaction_id 3)
02/01/2020 10:55:00, 6, def456, 1, 0 #(more than one day since transaction_id 4)
03/01/2020 08:55:00, 7, def456, 1, 1 #(considers transaction_id 6)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: already edited, hope it's clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],dayfirst=True)
df = df.set_index('timestamp')

_df = (df.groupby('buyer_id')['status'].rolling('24H').count()-1).reset_index()
_df.columns = ['buyer_id','timestamp','q_app_1d']
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.merge(_df)
df.head(7)
```

Comment: Hey Martín! Sure. Btw can you give an upvote to the answer as well?

Comment: i did, but since i'm new it says that it doesn't display it publicly ):

Comment: Oh! I missed that. Thanks, btw.